# SQL duplicate a row and then update

Tags: mysql

I need to create the duplicate of a row, and then update it.

```
  NAME      LOCATION    FLAG
  ====      ========    ====
  name1     location1    0
  name2     location2    0
```

first I have to select the row with NAME = name1 and LOCATION=location1 and create duplicate row and then update the NAME column with new value.

I can select the row by

`select  NAME,LOCATION,FLAG from TABLE where NAME=name1 and LOCATION=location1`

So the result should be like

```
  NAME      LOCATION    FLAG
  ====      ========    ====
  name1     location1    0
  name2     location2    0
  name3     location1    0
```

Comment: it is a little bit unclear

Comment: Like I show in the above, I need to insert 3rd row by duplicating the first row where the third row NAME column updated with new value name3. And the first row is selected with   `NAME = name1 and LOCATION=location1` condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly insert your select and just select your new name as value for the name-column

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (Name, Location, Flag) 
    select "New Name",LOCATION,FLAG from TABLE where NAME=name1 and LOCATION=location1
```